# pacman-key --init takes too long and does not exit

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have installed Arch Linux on my system and now when I try to install something using pacman, it gives me an error that the key 'xxxxxxx' was not found.

I Googled and found out I should have run `pacman-key --init`.
Now when I run `pacman-key --init`, it seems to go on for ever. I waited for more than 45 minutes, but still no result. I think it has something to do with generating Entropy.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. As the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman-key#Initializing_the_keyring) notes:

> For this initialization entropy is required. Moving your mouse around, pressing random characters at the keyboard or running some disk-based activity (for example in another console running `ls -R /` or `find / -name foo`) should generate entropy. If your system does not already have sufficient entropy, this step may take hours; if you actively generate entropy it will complete much more quickly.

You can read more about entropy in the Linux Kernel [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)#Entropy_in_the_Linux_kernel).

Comment: I ran the `ls -R /` many times in another terminal session (while running `pacman-key`), but no result.

Comment: Try something else that generates IO; redirecting output to a file and editing in `vi` is what I did last time around...

Comment: I did `ls -R / > somefile` and then `vi somefile`. Then I deleted a line and wrote the buffer to the disk (`dd` and `:w`) repeatedly. It completed very soon! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working in NSA, the bank or require really high security, you can:

```
ln -f /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

before running `pacman-key --init`. Using `/dev/urandom` is usually perfectly safe.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need vi or edit file , if you run `ls -R / | xargs -I {} echo {}`

Run that commad , and on new session run `pacman-key --init`

You get **key** less than 5 minutes

Comment: This does not add anything to the existing answer (why), but is an alternative approach to addressing it (how).